# Handling streaming uploads in flask with connexion

Tags: python-3.x, file-upload, flask

Using Flask, a user can (manually) use the `request.input_stream` to handle streaming uploads. For example to handle uploads that won't fit in memory - I'd like to combine that with the `connexion` library to get JSON validation.

With the `connexion` library I can't seem to work out how to access the raw data stream - it looks like the data all gets read in Connexion's [FlaskApi.get_request](https://github.com/zalando/connexion/blob/master/connexion/apis/flask_api.py#L226) from `EndOfRequestLifecycleDecorator` - which is happening well before calling any user defined handler function.

Is it possible to disable connexion - or at least not wrap the `flask.request` with `ConnexionRequest` for some endpoints?

On the server side I'd like to be able to do something like this in a request handler to access the raw stream:

```
if headers['Content-Type'] == "application/octet-stream":
    # This should work
    data = request.input_stream.read()
    print(len(data))
```

But the `input_stream` is empty because `connexion` has already slurped it up - which lead to problems if we are dealing with uploads that won't fit in memory.

Comment: Upstream issue in connexion's github - https://github.com/zalando/connexion/issues/592